# How to keep the snakemake shell file while running in cluster

Tags: snakemake

While running my snakemake file in cluster I keep getting an error,

```
snakemake -j 20 --cluster "qsub -o out.txt -e err.txt -q debug" -s 
seadragon/scripts/viral_hisat.snake --config json="<input file>" 
output="<output file>"
```

Now this gives me the follwing error,

```
Error in job run_salmon while creating output file 
/gpfs/home/user/seadragon/output/quant_v2_4/test.
ClusterJobException in line 58 of seadragon/scripts/viral_hisat.snake
:
Error executing rule run_salmon on cluster (jobid: 1, external: 156618.sn-mgmt.cm.cluster, jobscript: /gpfs/home/user/.snakemake/tmp.j9nb0hyo/snakejob.run_salmon.1.sh). For detailed error see the cluster log.
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Now I don't find any way to track the error, since my cluster does not give me an way to store the log files, on the other hand `/gpfs/home/user/.snakemake/tmp.j9nb0hyo/snakejob.run_salmon.1.sh` file is deleted immediately after finishing. 
Please let me know if there is an way to keep this shell file even if the snakemake fails.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a qsub user anymore, but if I remember correctly, stdout and stderr are stored in the working directory, under the jobid that Snakemake gives you under `external` in the error message.

Comment: Since you are specifying `-e err.txt` shouldn't the error log even be in there?

Comment: It does not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the standard output and standard error output to a file yourself instead of relying on the cluster or snakemake to do this for you.

Instead of the following

```
my_script.sh
```

Run the following

```
my_script.sh > output_file.txt 2> error_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not share definition of your rule but generally, if you define log in the rule and then collect both stder and stdout you should be able to access those exception messages in these logs.

You are saying that cluster does not give a way to store your log files. But surely snakemake jobs are running and accessing the same fileshare? Otherwise how input files would be accessed?

```py
rule abc:
    input: "input.txt"
    output: "output.txt"
    log: "logs/abc.log"
    shell: "somecommand {input} {output} &> {log}"
```